# Prove that $\int^1_0 \frac {n \sqrt{x}} {1+n^2x^2} \lambda (dx) \rightarrow 0 \ \ \text {as} \ \ n \rightarrow \infty$ using proven results.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that $$\int^1_0 \frac {n \sqrt{x}} {1+n^2x^2} \lambda (dx) \rightarrow 0 \ \ \text {as} \ \ n \rightarrow \infty$$

I've already proven as intermediary results that $$\frac {n \sqrt{x}} {1+n^2x^2} \le \frac {1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$$ for $x \in (0,1]$.

and for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $K \in (0, \infty)$ $$\int^K_0 x^{\alpha} \lambda(dx) = \begin{cases}
\infty,  & \text{if $\alpha \le -1$} \\
(\alpha+1)^{-1}K^{\alpha+1}, & \text{if $\alpha > -1$}
\end{cases}$$
. It should be pointed out $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure.

I know the rule: If $f \le g$ $\lambda$-almost-everywhere, $f,g \in \mathcal L(\lambda)$ then $\int f d \lambda \le \int g d \lambda$.

I should probably sandwich $\frac {n \sqrt{x}} {1+n^2x^2}$ between $0$ and $\frac {1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$, however, $\frac {1}{2 \sqrt{x}} =\frac {1}{2}x^{-1/2=\alpha}$ doesn't depend on $n$.

Advice needed! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Yes, how can I use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not have changes of variables for the Lebesgue integral yet - here's an outline of the more likely intended method.

If $$f_n(x) = \frac{n \sqrt x}{ 1 + n^2x^2},$$we have, as you pointed out $$|f_n(x)|\leq 1/2\sqrt x,$$ and $x \mapsto 1/2\sqrt x \in  L^1$, hence if $f_n(x)$ converges to some limit $f(x)$ for a.e. $x$, the DCT applies and the limit of $\int_0^1f_n(x) \, dx$ is just $\int_0^1f(x) \, dx$. Now look at the limit of $f_n(x)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, for fixed $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much @MattRigby. I appreciate how you incorporated what I'd already shown into the result.

Comment: I see that $f_n$ converges to $0$ ? You don't use the integral I've showed in OP for anything ?

Comment: The integral the OP is used to prove that $1/2 \sqrt x = \frac 12 x^{-1/2}$ is in $L^1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$0\leqslant\int^1_0 \frac {n \sqrt{x}} {1+n^2x^2} \mathrm dx\stackrel{\large [u=nx]}{=}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\int^n_0 \frac {\sqrt{u}} {1+u^2} \mathrm du\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\int^\infty_0 \frac {\sqrt{u}} {1+u^2} \mathrm du=\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Even more simply:
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac {n \sqrt{x}} {1+n^2x^2} \mathrm dx\stackrel{\large [u=nx]}{=}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\int^\infty_0 \frac {\sqrt{u}} {1+u^2} \mathrm du=\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: Thank you, did you apply any of my intermediary results ?

Comment: This answer sandwiches the function between functions and uses the order of the integrals you recall, and uses the convergence of the integrals of powers of $x$ that you recall--but apart from these...